# Need help understanding differentiability and directional derivatives

Tags: real-analysis

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpgOY.jpg)

I’m having a hard time trying to understand the concept of differentiability and directional derivatives in my real analysis class. There’s a link to the photo of how my professor defines them but it’s hard to follow. Does someone have a better and easy to understand definition or example? I understand the basics from R to R but higher order differentials is tough.

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer because it isn't clear what you do understand. Do you understand derivatives of functions of single variables? As it stands, you are asking for a lecture on directional derivatives.

Comment: This is a course this semester.

Comment: Although your question is closed, if you would like help on this question you still have some options. First, please follow our guidelines on [formatting and writing](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992), in particular *Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title.*

Comment: Second, instead of requesting an entire lecture with "images and examples", narrow your question down as much as you can to explain exactly what you are confused about. Also, give some extra context, for instance you can explain what you *do* know regarding the ordinary definition of the derivative, and what it is about this new kind of derivative that leads your understanding astray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented and I want to give a partial answer to your need of help, as far as I can.

Directional derivative measures how much a function changes at a given point and in a given direction. In your setting, $f:\Bbb{R}^m\rightarrow\Bbb{R}^n$, given by $(b_1,b_2,...,b_n)=f(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ is a vector function with $m$-independent and $n$-dependent variables. Note that both the point $\vec a=(a_1,a_2,...,a_m)$ and the direction $\vec u=(u_1,u_2,...,u_m)$ are in the domain $\Bbb{R}^m$, on the other hand the directional derivative $\vec Df(a,u)$ is in the codomain $\Bbb{R}^n$. When $n=1$, the directional derivative will be just a number. In the most special case, when $m=n=1$ and $u=1$, it will be the slope of the tangent line of the curve $b=f(a)$ at the given $a$.

You can find directional derivative in 2 ways. 1) From the original definition. 2) Practical way.

Example: Let $f(x,y)=(xy,x^2-y^2,x^3)$. Find the directioanal derivative of $f$ at $\vec a=(1,2)$ and in the direction $\vec u=(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$.

First way:

$\begin{align}\vec Df(\vec a,\vec u)&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(\vec a+t\vec u)-f(\vec a)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f((1,1)+t(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}))-f(1,1)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(1+\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}},1-\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}})-(1\times 1,1^2-1^2,1^3)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1-\frac{t^2}{2},2\sqrt{2}t,1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}t,\frac{3}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}t^3)-(1,0,1)}{t}\\
&=\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}\frac{(-\frac{t^2}{2},2\sqrt{2}t,\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}t,\frac{3}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}t^3)}{t}\\
&=(0,2\sqrt{2},\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}})
\end{align}$

Second way: In the second definition of the text you shared, the matrix $B$ is the derivative of the function at $\vec a$ and we denote it by $Df(\vec a)$. Then, here is the directional derivative: $\vec Df(\vec a,\vec u)=Df(\vec a)\vec u^{T}$. I wrote $u$ transpose because it is column matrix and above we were writing $u$ as row matrix. It is confusing but we have to adjust to the definition. I hope this is a good link: https://mathinsight.org/derivative_matrix The derivative matrix in general form is written there.

In our example,
$Df=\left[\begin{array} .y&x\\ 2x&-2y\\3x^2&0\end{array}\right]$ and
$Df(1,1)=\left[\begin{array} .1&1\\ 2&-2\\3&0\end{array}\right]$ and hence
$$\vec Df(\vec a,\vec u)=\left[\begin{array} .1&1\\ 2&-2\\3&0\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array} .\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array} .0\\2\sqrt{2}\\\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}\end{array}\right]=(0,2\sqrt{2},\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}).$$

As I said, vectors being column matrix in one place and row matrix in other place is disturbing.